# What is the use case of the declaration of array like below in C-Language (It is valid one dont say it is error)

Tags: c, data-structures

In my company, when I am looking in the code part,
I was wondering when I see an array variable declaration similar to like this

`int arr[0]`; (Using c language)

Could anyone help me to state that what this declaration meant for?
How this declaration can make use of realtime of codepart?

Comment: You build with GCC? And this is the last member of a struct?

Comment: what they will do by allocating memory of 0??

Comment: It's malformed unless the answer to both of my leading questions (which you ignored) is yes.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, it is the last member. What is the result and why?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Story Teller :) ,Nope ,I have not tried in gcc i just seen in the huge code part where in one funtion they have declared the variable as above one

Comment: It was used so that memory for a `struct` could be allocated dynamically, making the last member a variable length array (by overrunning its defined length into allocated memory).

Comment: @satishkumar : is `int arr[0];` part of a `struct`? Please show some code where `arr` is used. And: is your code C or C++?

Comment: Please re-write your question title to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

It is an error insofar that it is neither standard C nor standard C++.

This is the old (i.e. pre-C99) way of inserting a variable length array as a `struct` member, which was never standard C although some compilers (e.g. GCC) support it as an extension. It has to be the last member of the `struct`.

Post C99, the now *standard* way to do this is to use empty brackets.

For C++ you're out of luck - variable length arrays are not standard C++. But you can use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Could you expain with an example please....

Comment: You already read the GCC documentation StoryTeller linked in a comment, right? That contains an example, so why are you asking for another one?

Comment: It is related to the 'struct hack', but the struct hack needed a dimension of 1 because 0 isn't valid in C.

Comment: Indeed. The "struct hack" used 1 and had poorly-defined behavior (because you'd write out of bounds of the array and there might also be padding) and the gcc zero-length array had well-defined behavior but was not standard. This gcc non-standard extension lead to the introduction of flexible array members in C99. Therefore both the "struct hack" and GCC zero-length arrays are bad and obsolete methods.